# Analysis method for categorical survey

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis

I have a survey response like the following:

```
Q1              Q2                              Q3

Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Very satisfied  About what I expected           10
Very satisfied  About what I expected           8
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Satisfied       About what I expected           4
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Satisfied       About what I expected           8
Satisfied       Much shorter than I expected    10
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         9
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Satisfied       Shorter than I expected         8
Satisfied       About what I expected           8
Satisfied       Shorter than I expected         5
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         10
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    9
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Satisfied       Much shorter than I expected    9
Very satisfied  About what I expected           9
Very satisfied  About what I expected           10
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         10
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Very satisfied  About what I expected           10
Neutral         Shorter than I expected         8
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         6
Satisfied       About what I expected           8
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         9
Unsatisfied     About what I expected           3
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Satisfied       Shorter than I expected         9
Neutral         Shorter than I expected         6
Unsatisfied     Did not receive a response      1
Very satisfied  Much shorter than I expected    10
Very unsatisfied    About what I expected       1
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         10
Very satisfied  Shorter than I expected         8
```

What would be the best way to answer the following question: if responder answer Q2 with "Much shorter than expected", then  what is the probability Q3 would be a 10.

I'm looking for explicit answers or how to guides to that I can learn to do this in the future. I would like to accomplish this in excel or pandas.

Can I use Logistic regression and assign a dummy variable to Q2? Can I somehow create a correlation matrix to see how correlated the responses of Q2 are with Q3?

Comment: ...If they *did* select "Much shorter than expected", what *would* the probability `Q3` is a 10 be? It looks like it'd be 100%, no?  It's not very clear what you're looking for, or how to arrive at it.  What if they choose "About what I expected"? The probability that `Q3` then is 1/3...Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated with the entire survey. I dont think just calculating the percentage of answers that fit my question will give the actually probability.

Comment: so what's your question? How to calculate probability?

Comment: my question is as stated above "if a responder answers Q2 with 'Much shorter than expected' what is the probability they will answer Q3 with '10'"

Comment: This may be a question for mathematics SO, it doesn't seem to necessarily be an Excel question.  It's just asking about how to calculate probability, no?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about calculating probability, or other mathematical operation, and not a programming question.

Comment: I am asking for help in implementing the solution in excel or pandas so I dont believe it is off topic.

Comment: @Precise_V5 your original question has been answered. You are now asking new questions - of which the answer is simply "yes." I have also voted to close.

Comment: @user1274820 it has not been answered. I am asking for a different solution than what you have given. If you cant give me one that is fine but please let others help.

Comment: I think we're getting hung up on what your actual question is here - Excel is just a tool that can help you set up data and analyse.  If you're asking *how* to determine the probability, that is a little off topic for SO, which is mainly for programming questions/solutions.  If you have a formula for your probability, and are trying to determine how apply in Excel, let us know what the formula is.  I see that each "much shorter than expected" value is 10, and only 10. But I don't know what value you expect for "Shorter than I expected", since it's different (some are 10, some are 8, etc)...

Comment: @BruceWayne not all "much shorter than expected" value is 10, for example line 16 and 18.

Comment: @Precise_V5 you're new here - Bruce and I have been here for awhile. We can help you write formulas/macros to apply formulas, but we do not teach statistics or math - that's not what we're here for. You asked (originally) how to calculate the probability and gave a dataset. I have shown you how to do that. You then edit your question to instead ask "Can I use Logistic regression"? "Can I somehow create a correlation matrix?" These are math questions, not programming questions. I.E. off topic.

Comment: where should I move the my post to? cross validated?

Comment: @Precise_V5 You can try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate this using a formula:

`=(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,"Much shorter than I expected",$C$2:$C$37,10)/COUNTIF($B42:$B$37,"Much shorter than I expected"))*100`

We give it the range `B2:B37` to check for the answer "Much shorter than I expected"

When we find it, we check to see if they gave a 10 for Q3.

Then we take the number where it is true over the total number times they answered "Much shorter than I expected", multiply by 100 and round to 2 decimal places.

**Formula Example:**

[image: Formula]

You can also modify this formula to accept different parameters:

`=(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,E2,$C$2:$C$37,F2)/COUNTIF($B$2:$B$37,E2))*100`

[image: Example2]

And if you're just wondering about the math to calculate probability, here are the steps:

1. Define your events and outcomes.
2. Divide the number of events by the number of possible outcomes.
3. Multiply the answer by 100 to make it a percent.
4. Use the percentage as your answer.

http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Probability

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not looking to calculate the percent of responses however. I am looking to use some type of modeling or stats technique (bayesian, logisitic regression, chi-squared test for independence, etc...). we cant assume here that the distribution of answers to the survey is representative of a larger population. our statistical error would be quite large since the sample size is so small.

Comment: @Precise_V5 you haven't actually said what you want. Are you literally just asking "can you please teach me every way to analyze data?" I don't understand what it is you're asking for anymore.

Comment: 1. if responder answer Q2 with "Much shorter than expected", then what is the probability Q3 would be a 10? - looking for help answering this

2. how would i go about implementing such solution in excel or pandas - looking for help doing this

The above are my two questions. I am trying to give as much information as possible but now it seems I must make this very explicit.

Comment: That's exactly what I answered for you already. Given the data set, the answer is `83.33%`. I have also shown you how to get this solution in excel.

Comment: You realize there are many differnet ways to calculate probability right? I responded to your answer and why I dont think it is accurate but I will say again - **we cant assume here that the distribution of answers to the survey is representative of a larger population. our statistical error would be quite large since the sample size is so small.**

Does the above make sense? because of that I am looking for a more robust way of measuring correlation between how Q2 is answered and how Q3 is answered.